# Show that if $a$ is an integer, $(a^2-a)/2$ is an integer too.

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Please help me on this number theory problem. Show that $a\in\mathbb Z$, then $\frac{a^2-a}{2}\in\mathbb Z$.

Comment: Please edit to add math latex syntax. Also, is that supposed to be a conditional?

Comment: @Emisor: We do _not_ require new users to know how to use Mathjax. You're free to edit the question yourself to show the new user how it's done.

Answer (score 4):

You can factor the numerator and you will get: $\frac{a^2 - a}{2} = \frac{a(a-1)}{2}$. But on the other hand it's well known that $n$ divides at least one (to be more rigorous, exactly one) out of $n$ consecutive integers. Now using this we have that 2 divides one of $a$ or $a-1$, hence the proof.

Answer (score 3):

**Hint:** Being an integer, $a$ is either even or odd. Divide into two cases where $a=2k$ and $a=2k+1$, respectively, and show that your desired conclusion is true in both of them.

Answer (score 0):

If $a$ is even, say $a=2k$, then $$\frac{a^2-a}2=\frac{4k^2-2k}{2}=2k^2-k \in Z;$$

if $a$ is odd, say $a=2k+1$, then $$\frac{a^2-a}2=\frac{4k^2+4k+1-(2k+1)}{2}=\frac{4k^2+2k}{2}=2k^2+k\in Z.$$

Comment: That looks like an unhelpfully complete answer to post for an obvious homework question that the OP has not done any work on themself.